# Convert the MySql query to CakePhp 2.0

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

How do I convert this MySql query to CakePhp's find.
And please tell me how can i practice writing Find queries in cakephp

```
select distinct trips.fk_userid from spots, trips 
where spots.fk_tripid = trips.id 
    and trips.isapproved = 1 
    and spots.id in (".$row[$first_index]['spot_list'].")
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model can be `Trip` and you can query like this

```
$this->Trip->query("select distinct trips.fk_userid from spots, trips where spots.fk_tripid = trips.id and trips.isapproved = 1 and spots.id in (".$row[$first_index]['spot_list'].")");
```

or

You should create Trip and Spot model and in Trip model, you have to have this in Spot model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Trip' => array(
        'className'     => 'Trip',
        'foreignKey'    => 'fk_tripid'
    )
);
```

and query it like this:

```
$this->Spot->find('all', array(
   'fields' => array("distinct Trip.fk_userid"), 
   'conditions' => array(
       'Trip.isapproved' => 1, 
       'Spot.id' => $row[$first_index]['spot_list']
)
));
```

Comment: i have a model of spot, and it has
public $belongsTo = array(
  'Trip' => array(
   'className' => 'Trip',
   'foreignKey' => 'fk_tripid',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => ''
  ));

Comment: Is Trip belongs to Spot or is it viceversa?